# (Salesforce Marketing Cloud) Getting Journey Details by Id on Postman

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, integration, postman

I have been using Postman to get Journey Details by Id (The real task is to update it through cloudpages but I want to solve this first).

I've been following the official documentation but it doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this:

URI: (MyRestURI)/interaction/v1/interactions/{JourneyId}?VersionNumber=1

Request type: GET

Content-Type: application/json

Authorization: Bearer {MyToken}

The only response I have been getting is : "Interaction Studio"

Comment: How did you retrieve the Journey Id?

Comment: Using Query Studio